# Bottom Up drawer in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new to react native. I want to create a menu slider like **control center** in IOS. I thought I can use [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) but the library doesn't provide a way to open drawer from the bottom. can you guys suggest something to implement that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you are looking for are called Bottom Sheets in Material Design (see [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html) for examples) and Action Sheets in iOS (customized action sheets more precisely, like [this one](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController)).

I found two React Native libraries which implement Bottom Sheets (so only for android):

- https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-bottom-sheet-behavior
- https://github.com/WhatAKitty/react-native-bottom-sheet

And this library implements custom Action Sheets (so only for ios):

- https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-custom-action-sheet

I didn't find any RN library which works for both platforms, so we will have to be happy with what we've got. Good luck!

Edit: Since my answer a new package came out: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet. Thanks @thibautnoah for pointing it out.

Comment: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet seems the way to go

Answer (score 13):

This library react-native-modalbox implements this behaviour. It's cross platform as well and pure javascript.

https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Comment: In this case it's not your fault because the question was off-topic, but please note that in general, an answer that recommends some tool or library must demonstrate how it solves the problem at hand in the answer itself.

Comment: How's it off-topic? He defined a problem set: Menu slider that implements a drawer opening from the bottom. And I listed a library that has the capability to open a drawer from the bottom.

Comment: They are asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 7):

I made this [react-native-bottom-drawer](https://github.com/donaldmorton/react-native-bottom-drawer) module based on [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer), it's pure javascript to it works on IOS and Android.

Its on an early stage so feel free to PR

Comment: your package is not listed on npm. When i try to install react-native-bottom-drawer, this one gets installed instead https://github.com/rationalappdev/react-native-bottom-drawer. Can you please publish your package with a different name.