# React Native: Music player in tabbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, audio-player

i am trying to make a music player app with react native. i haven't decided the component for playing music in the app yet. what is important to me is that i have music player controller in tabbar above the tabs (which is created by react-native-router-flux) like spotify app (i have highlighted the tabbar i mean in the picture below) and be able to control the playing music in every page in my project.
how is it done in react native and what component should i use?

[image: spotify app]

Comment: Try This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265568/bottom-up-drawer-in-react-native

Comment: @PeterHassaballah thank you so much. it worked!

Comment: What exactly you use I'm faced the same thing

Comment: @MMILAD can you share more info please